# ElasticSearch: why is query_string case insensitive and wildcard case sensitive?

Tags: elasticsearch, request, wildcard

Why is it when you do a query_string query on a field it's case insensitive and a wildcard query is case sensitive? I would've thought the two would behave similarly.

This query_string query returns results

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "name:*HILTON*"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Where as this wildcard query doesn't

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
        "wildcard" : {
          "name" : "*HILTON*"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because [Wild card query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) works for `not analyzed` fields.

As per the documentation:

> The prefix, wildcard, and regexp queries operate on terms. If you use them to query an analyzed field, they will examine each term in the field, not the field as a whole.
>
> Wild card query matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression **(not analyzed)**.